# Firebase Integration android app error Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED]

Tags: android, firebase

I have integrated firebase in my android app but I am getting error

> Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED]

My App Application Id is "Com.Example.Package"

Package Name : "com.example.package"

Do I get this error because of application id in capital letter ?

If I changed my application id in small letter then app working fine

Please provide solution where I will not change my application id and                      also integrate firebase analytics

Comment: Don't include a screenshot of you gradle file (or in general of any textual content). Please include the text itself.

Answer (score 0):

Add **packagingOptions** to the App level gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        ...
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            ...
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile ...
}
```

Add **dependencies** to project level gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> My App Application Id is "Com.Example.Package"
>
> Package Name : "com.example.package"
>
> Do I get this error because of application id in capital letter ?

Yes. Application ids must start with a lowercase letter between `a` and `z`.

The question is a little short on details, but generally the application id you specify in build.gradle gets replaced as the manifest package name, and manifest package names need to start with lowercase.

Comment: in my app, i cannot change my app id because an app is live in google play ,when i integrate the firebase in my app then app give exception > "Bad Class Com.Example.Package.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" ,so i need a solution where i will not change my app id

Answer (score 0):

Application id is different from package name. It is always lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

Exception in log Bad Class 
"your capital package name.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
Add these lines in manifest with your capital package name

```
<permission
             android:name="your capital package name.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
            tools:node="remove"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="your capital package name.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        tools:node="remove"
        />
```